# container.lookup('store:main') returning undefined

Tags: ember.js

I'm using EmberJS and I have an initializer for loading up the current user in a store. I have no idea why its not working. My current initializer is:

```
export function initialize(container, application) {
  var store = container.lookup('store:main');
  console.log(store);
}

export default {
  name: 'current-user',
  after: 'preload',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

When I log `container` and convert it to a global variable in the console, and run `temp1.lookup('store:main')` I get an object. I'm pretty confused right now as to why the initializer isn't able to load the store.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's likely because your initializer is running before the one that sets up the store. The Ember Data initializer can be found [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/25987d6b42fb6cef49573d29df9683dca6496a76/packages/ember-data/lib/ember-initializer.js). As described in the [initializer API](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#method_initializer), you need to do something like this:

```
export default {
    name: 'current-user',
    after: ['preload', 'ember-data'],
    initialize: initialize
};
```